# How to get maximum element from a table from DynamoDb AWS Console?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I am trying to create a database table in NoSQL in order to be able to retrieve the element with a maximum value in one of its columns.

Suppose the SQL schema looks like this:

```
Table_Page
```

PageId: int(10) - PK

Name: varbinary(255)

RevisionId: int(10) - FK

```
Table_Revision
```

RevisionId: int(10) - PK

Text: varbinary(255)

Rev_TimeStamp: binary(14)

**How** could I design the schema in **Amazon DynamoDB Console** such that it supports a query to retrieve the page with the latest Revision? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the query you want to do is, given a page_id, find the revision of that page with the largest timestamp. (instead of finding a revision of largest timestamp, regardless of page_id)

You can design your table in DynamoDB like this:

```
Table_Page_Revision
HashKey: PageId
RangeKey: Rev_TimeStamp
Attrubute 1: RevisionId
Attribute 2: Text
```

Then another table just to store the name of a page:

```
Table_Page_Name
HashKey: PageId
Attribute: Name
```

To do your query, you can use this pseudo code:

```
Table_Page_Revision.query(HashKey="Your Page Id", ScanIndexForward=False, Limit=1)
```

We set the "scan forward" parameter to false, meaning it will start from the item with large range key to smaller range key (DESC). We also set the limit to 1 which means we are only interested in getting 1 item returned. Combined together this gives you the item with the largest "Rev_TimeStamp"

Comment: Do you know if this can be achieved via the DynamoDB web interface? I solved it using your suggestion with Java AWS SDK but I could not find how to set a limit from the web interface Amazon provides.

Comment: I didn't see the option either. So it will return more results than you want. But the first one is the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I think you are looking for a solution in the "RDB" field that don't match the freedom of data modeling that DynamodB gives you.

I managed to save a completely separated record that is the "latest version" of the data, and using a suitable sorting key, you can directly get the latest data in a single query and in "blazingly fast" (:D) fashion.

Simply add a chunk of code after every put command (or update, or upsert) that update  the single "latestVersion" sorting key.

In your example you don't show which are the Partition Key and the Sorting Key, but I imagine a model like that:

```
Hashkey(int - Partition Key) | version(int Sorting Key) | data(json) | created(date)
```

If you switch the version type and go for something like:

```
HashKey(int - Partition Key) | version(int Sorting Key) | data(json) | created(date)
```

You can index the sorting key wiht somethig like:

```
HashKey| RevisionId   | data         | created 
01     |    00000     | {latestData} | ...latestTimeStamp 
01     |    00001     | { someData } | ...someTimeStamp 
01     |    00002     | { someData } | ...someTimeStamp 
02     |    00000     | {latestData} | ...latestTimeStamp
02     |    00001     | { someData } | ...someTimeStamp
```

When you'll insert the 01 - 00003 data, you'll overwrite the 00000 too.

Doing this, when you get the HashKey + 00000 you have always the latest data of your HashKey

Hope it helps.